# Listening to Firestore Websocket

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Can we listen to Firestore Web socket that is used by Firestore to connect to internet? The idea is to sense the status of Web socket that helps to identify if internet is working or not?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.  Not only is there not an API for this, the Firestore connection doesn't try to stay open all the time, so you can't reliably use it to determine if you're online (unlike the Realtime Database connection).

Comment: Idea is to check somewhere (may be listening Firestore or other way) only when we come to know Internet is not working. When Internet works no need to listen. Can you have ways to handle it?

Comment: I understand.  As I said, it's not possible.